# Cakephp AuthComponent: Login successfull despite wrong password

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, passwords

I'm running a 2.2.2 CakePHP Application, everything works as desired. Now I'm developing a Android App for it and therefore need to create the interfaces between those two apps. That's why I need to login users manually. So I created a whole new controller, the AndroidController, in order to bundle everything at one place. First thing to do would be the Login-Action. So I setup the following controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

/**
 * Android Controller
 * 
 * @package       app.Controller
 */
class AndroidController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('RequestHandler','Auth');
    public $uses = array('User');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

    public function login() {
        //For testing purposes
        $postarray = array('_method' => 'POST','data' => array('User' => array('email' => 'user@gmail.com', 'password' => 'THISisDEFINITELYaWRONGpassword')));

        $id = $this->tryToGetUserID($postarray['data']['User']['email']);
        if($id == 0){
            //return Error json, unknown User
            $this->set('result', array(
                'tag' => 'login',
                'success' => 0,
                'error' => 1,
                'error_msg' => 'Unknown User'           
            )); 
        }else{
        //  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $postarray['data']['User'] = array_merge($postarray['data']['User'], array('id' => $id));
                    $this->User->id = $id;
                if ( $this->Auth->login($postarray['data']['User'])) {
                    // Login successfull
                    $this->User->saveField('lastlogin', date(DATE_ATOM));
                    $user = $this->User->find('all', array(
                        'recursive' => 0, //int
                        'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id)
                    ));
                    $loggedInUser = array(
                        'tag' => 'login',
                        'success' => 1,
                        'error' => 0,
                        'uid' => '??',
                        'user' => array(
                            'name' => $user['0']['User']['forename'].' '.$user['0']['User']['surname'],
                            'email' => $user['0']['User']['email'],
                            'created_at' => $user['0']['User']['created'],
                            'updated_at' => $user['0']['User']['lastlogin']                 
                        )
                    );
                    $this->set('result', $loggedInUser);                
                } else {
                    // Login failed
                    $this->set('result', array(
                        'tag' => 'login',
                        'success' => 0,
                        'error' => 2,
                        'error_msg' => 'Incorrect password!'            
                    ));
                }
        //  }
        }

    }

    public function tryToGetUserID($email = null) { 
        $user = $this->User->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.email' => $email)
        ));
        if(!empty($user)){
            return array_keys($user)['0'];
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

You need to know that this method will be called as a POST request, but for testing purposes I manually created a post-array. In future I will use the $_POST array.
So, what happens: The Login with a registered user works, but it works every time! Even though the password is wrong or missing! The program never reaches the part in code with the "Login failed" comment.

Am I missing something here..?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not how any login in any cake version should ever look like, especially in 2.x. You should use (custom) Auth adapters, not something like this that is not transparent and can easily backfire (as you just lined out).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) you will notice that AuthComponent::login() will ...

> In 2.x $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in with whatever data is posted

Comment: Ok, I see...@mark, I can only try to implement what's specified in the documentation and I thought that would be the way to log in users manually as written in [this chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in). There's no hint at this point that the data is irrelevant. Which is really strange...
So how am I supposed to log users in manually?

Comment: You are not understanding the example you provided, in that example the user is being logged "manually" because he/she just registered.

Read the entire chapter.